# How to use windows keyboard shortcut with just typing on keyboard , without goint to anywhere, Dos, Run etc

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

How to use windows keyboard shortcut with just typing on keyboard , without goint to anywhere, Dos, Run etc.

Like if i just press CALC then calculator should be opend

Comment: What keyboard are you even using that has that button?

Comment: I think he means to Just Type CALC in nowhere and the calculator will open.. I dont think thats possible. You must make windows understand that what you're typing is a command. or else, if you're typing in Word and type calc, the calculator will open everytime..
Win7 is better here, just press Windows key and start typing the command. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Definitely possible with [Autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com), but it will probably get very annoying after a while due to the fact that the calc substring is used in a lot of other words. If you typed words such as calculus, calcify, or miscalculate then you'd have a calculator window opening up.

Nonetheless, if you still want to have this, you can use hotstrings to achieve this easily:

```
:*:calc::
run calc
return
```

I'd suggest maybe using a modifier key though for reasons explained above. You could use a less frequently used key such as <kbd>Escape</kbd> and after pressing it, it can listen for a sequence of keys. Maybe incorporate [KeyWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm) into the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Jitendra,

Windows 7 has the feature I think you're looking for.

Press the Windows key, then:

- type CALC and press Enter and the calculator appears.
- type INTERNET and press Enter and Internet Explorer appears.
- type GOOGLE and press Enter and Internet Explorer appears with Google webpage loaded.
- type OUTLOOK and press Enter and Microsoft Outlook appears.

I love this feature!

Under Windows 7, this typing goes straight into the "Search programs and files" field, which shortlists all the matches from every program in your Start menu.  If you type a word that is unique among all your shortcuts, then you just press Enter it runs that program.  If there are a few matches, you might have to press down arrow a few times before pressing Enter.  If you add more custom shortcuts to your Start Menu, these are also listed by this "Search programs and files" feature.  It's all lightning quick (at least it's quick on my PC  ;-).

A word of warning ... Windows 7 takes a bit of getting used to.  Be prepared to spend some time to learn how to use it productively.

***Staying on Windows XP***

If you're committed to staying on Windows XP, check out the Run feature.  Press Windows+R, then type CALC and press Enter.  It doesn't work for everything, but can be quite useful if you know the .EXE filenames.

Windows XP also allows you to customise you're Start Menu, press Windows+R and type:

```
%homepath%\Start Menu
```

... then press Enter, to bring up an explorer window in the Start Menu area.

I put an "Internet" subdirectory under my "Start Menu", with a shortcut to "Google" in it.  That way I can press Windows,I,G (just 3 keys) and Google appears.  I set up some other subdirectories under "Start Menu" for other shortcuts:

- Accessories
- Explore
- Go To
- Jump
- My
- Quick Access

You can also put shortcuts directly in the "Start Menu" directory.  I access my Timesheet program by pressing Windows,T (just 2 keys).

Note that these keystrokes depend on having the XP Start Menu configured as a "Classic start menu".  Right-click on the Start button, then select "Properties", then choose "Classic start menu" and click OK.

Matthew

Comment: Vista also had this feature.

Comment: Hi Macha, I never used Vista.  Does Vista have the "Classic" Start Menu feature like XP, or the "Search programs and files" feature like Windows 7?